# ¿Cuál es el significado de utlizar un símbolo más (+) dentro de un WHERE en una consulta SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-11g

**Situación**

Al ejecutar las siguientes consultas se optiene el mismo número de registros, quisiera saber cuál es la diferencia de utilizar un `(+)` al final de la consulta.

```
SELECT A.IDTABLAA,B.NOMBRETABLAB
FROM TABLA_A A, TABLA_B B
WHERE A.IDTABLAA=B.IDTABLAB
```

> --Record Count: 2.265

```
SELECT A.IDTABLAA, B.NOMBRETABLAB
FROM TABLA_A A, TABLA_B B
WHERE A.IDTABLAA=B.IDTABLAB(+)
```

> --Record Count: 2.265

**Entorno**

- Base de datos: Oracle 11g

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Esa es la sintaxis antigua de Oracle de `LEFT OUTER JOIN` antes que se estandarice

La equivalente con la sintaxis actual sería:

```sql
SELECT A.IDTABLAA, B.NOMBRETABLAB
FROM TABLA A LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLA B
ON A.IDTABLAA=B.IDTABLAB
```

La diferencia es que con el `LEFT OUTER JOIN` ( o (+) al lado derecho del `=` en el `WHERE` ) se incluyen en el resultado todas las filas de la tabla `A` a pesar que no tengan correspondencia en la tabla `B` colocando un `NULL` como valor en ese caso.

Answer (score 19):

El operador `(+)` indica que se hará un OUTER JOIN, dependiendo de la posición del operador. Un OUTER JOIN regresa todas las filas que cumplen con la condición especificada, y además 0 o más filas de una tabla que no tengan coincidencia en la otra tabla.

Para hacer un `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, el operador debe aparecer en la tabla del lado derecho:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLA_A JOIN TABLA_B(*)
```

En el caso específico de tus tablas se está realizando un `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, por lo que el resultado serán todas las filas que cumplan con la condición de `JOIN` y además las filas de `A.IDTABLAA` que no tengan coincidencia.

Para hacer un `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`, el operador debe aparecer en la tabla del lado izquierdo:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLA_A(*) JOIN TABLA_B
```

También hay que considerar las siguientes restricciones:

- Sólo se puede usar el operador `(*)` dentro de la cláusula `WHERE`
- Para que los resultados sean correctos en una consulta con más de un `JOIN`, se debe usar el operador en todos los `JOIN`.
- No se puede usar para realizar un self-join
- Si en la cláusula `WHERE` aparece `(*)`, no se puede combinar con otras condiciones con los operadores `AND` o `OR`.

Este es un operador exclusivo de Oracle, por lo que si quisieras migrar este código a algún otro RDBMS es recomendable usar la sintaxis estándar de `OUTER JOINS`.